# How to get started with Myrrix recommendation

Tags: mahout, myrrix

I just discovered this recommender framework called Myrrix (http://myrrix.com/) couple of days ago but I think the website lacks proper documentations on how to implement a basic recommender. Does anyone know of any example code/tutorial on how to build a basic recommender with Myrrix? I've used Mahout before; how similar is myrrix to mahout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all you need to get started: http://myrrix.com/quick-start/
What else are you looking for?
It is not a library in which you implement your own recommender.